# Is it possible to bind complex objects that may have duplicate property names to sql-view?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-view

I am willing to create a view that matches with the model below.Imagine my model is as follows.(I removed remaining code for brevity)

```
public class ProposalData : DefaultEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public virtual DebtorData Debtor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CreditorData> Creditor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WarranterData> Warranter { get; set; }
```

I tried to create a view using sql management but because Debtor,Creditor,Warranter all have id column,it throwed the below error.

[image]

I know what caused this error but I haven't found a solution yet.Isn't it possible to create a view that matches with complex object/entity without changing my model or adding any data annotation ?

Comment: you could just type Debtor.ID, Creditor.ID, Warranter.ID  .. whenever you have tables contain columns with the same name, you always specify the columns with a prefix of the table name to be distinguished.

Comment: Just don't check "AllColumns" everywhere.